# $K_{0}(R) =\mathbb{Z}$ but some f.g. projective not stably free?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

This question is motived by this recent [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27424/a-ring-such-that-all-projectives-are-stably-free-but-not-all-projectives-are-free/).

$K_{0}(R)=\mathbb{Z}$ is often used as a euphemism for saying that every finitely generated projective module is stably free; however, there are some subtleties involved.

The statement that every finitely generated projective module is stably free is equivalent to saying that $K_{0}(R)$ is generated by the isomorphism class of $R$. To show that the two are not the same, consider $R = M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$, $2\times 2$ matrices over the complex numbers. Devissage tells us that $K_{0}(R)=\mathbb{Z}$, with the unique simple module as a generator. However, every stably free projective has to have even length as an $R$ module, as length($R$)=2, and thus the unique simple module (projective as $R$ is semisimple) is not stably free.

Are there any commutative examples of this phenomena? More precisely, is there a commutative ring with $K_{0}(R)=\mathbb{Z}$, but with f.g. projectives which aren't stably free? A commutative noetherian one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $R$ is a commutative ring with $K_{0}(R)=\mathbb{Z}$, then $\mathop{\rm Spec} R$ is connected, because otherwise $R$ would split as a product, and $K_{0}(R)$ would contain a copy of $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. Hence there is a well defined surjective rank homomorphism $K_{0}(R) \to \mathbb{Z}$, which must then be an isomorphism. Since $R$ has rank 1, it follows that the class of $R$ generates. This implies that every projective module is stably free.

Comment: Hah! I've lost a few seconds trying to explain what goes wrong in the noncommutative situation!

Comment: Victor, this is not a race.

Comment: I didn't imply it was, Angelo, in fact, I voted you up immediately, which is why you have an extra point as of now. But have you noticed an uncanny resemblance between our solutions? It's even more amazing, since I've completely rewritten mine twice before posting.

Comment: Yes, our solutions are identical. It is a very natural idea, so it is not so suprising. Sorry if I was brusque, I did not mean to be offensive, but sometimes I find that this reputation business generates a lot of competition, which I don't like.

Comment: And I absolutely agree with you about the reputation business! It's a natural idea, but it took me some effort to come up with a polished presentation. I am proud that it came out nearly the same as the one done by a professional algebraic geometer (I am a representation theorist myself). 

Answer (score 7):

No. Since $K_0(R)=\mathbb{Z},$ the ring $R$ is not a direct product, i.e. $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is connected. Therefore, every projective module has constant rank.
The rank function is an isomomorphism between $K_0(R)$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ which maps the free module of rank 1 $R$ into the generator 1 of $\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, every projective module is stably free.

In your noncommutative example, $M^{\oplus n}\simeq R,$ so the "rank" of $M$ isn't an integer.

Comment: Or if you use uniform rank instead of naive "rank", the rank of $R$ isn't 1.

Comment: You've lost to an angel. Not a big loss.

Answer (score 4):

Under the mild condition that the rank of a free module is an invariant, the free modules form a monoid isomorphic to $\mathbb N$. This induces an injection:
$$f: \mathbb Z \to K_0(R) $$

Then every projective is stably free is equivalent to $f$ being an isomorphism.

When $R$ is commutative, $f$ splits (since one can map $R$ to a field, which induces a map $K_0(R) \to \mathbb Z$ such  that when compose to $f$ is the identity). So in this case $f$ is an isomorphism iff $K_0(R)\cong \mathbb Z$. It works whenever the map $f$ splits.

In your example, $f$ is the injection $2\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 3):

When $R$ is commutative, $K_0(R)$ is a commutative ring with
multiplicative unit the class $[R]$ of $R$. The only ring structure
with additive group $\mathbb{Z}$ is the familiar one, so every element
of $K_0(R)$ is an integer multiple of $[R]$ - every finitely generated
projective $R$-module is stably free.

When $R$ is non-commutative, there is no natural ring structure on $K_0(R)$
which explains how Rishi's phenomenon occurs.

Comment: I'm used to the notation that $K_0(R)$ is the Grothendieck group of finitely generated modules modulo short exact sequences, and $K^0(R)$ is the one generated by locally free modules. Only $K^0(R)$ has a natural ring structure. But maybe this is not standard notation?

Comment: David, my use of $K_0(R)$ for the Grothendieck group of finitely
generated projective modules (modulo direct sums) is
completely standard; it is used in Bass's *Algebraic K-Theory*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to disagree with all of the previous answers, and say that there is an example. This will relate to the issue of notation that I raise in my comment to Robin's answer.

Take $R = \mathbb{Z}/p^2$, for $p$ some prime. Every finitely generated $R$-module is a direct sum of modules of the form $\mathbb{Z}/p$ and $\mathbb{Z}/p^2$. From the short exact sequence $0 \to \mathbb{Z}/p \to \mathbb{Z}/p^2 \to \mathbb{Z}/p \to 0$, we get the relation $[\mathbb{Z}/p^2] = 2 [\mathbb{Z}/p]$ in $K_0(R)$. So $K_0(R)$ is generated by $[\mathbb{Z}/p]$. As length is an invariant on $K_0(R)$, there are no further relations. So $K_0(R) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, generated by $[\mathbb{Z}/p]$, and $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is not stably free.

There should be many similar examples whenever $R$ is not generically reduced.

Comment: It depends of what you mean by $K_0$. The natural interpretation seemed to be that of the Grothendieck group of projective finitely generated modules; if you take all finitely generated modules, then of course you are right.

Comment: I think $K_0$ for projectives is standard notation. The Grothendieck group of f.g. modules is often called $G_0$. 

Comment: Let me point out why $K_0$ and $K^0$ is great notation: the functorial properties of these groups are analogous to those of homology and cohomology, respectively. $K^0$ is a ring, and $K_0$ is a $K^0$-module. If we have a map $\mathrm{Spec}\ R \to \mathrm{Spec}\ S$, then we get induced maps $K_0(R) \to K_0(S)$ and $K^0(S) \to K^0(R)$.

Comment: David, that's nice! Do you have some reference for your notation? 

Comment: David, your notation is at odds with that of Hyman Bass :-)

Comment: Just to clarify, by $K_{0}(R)$ I was referring to the Grothendieck group of the f.g. projectives, not all f.g. modules.

Comment: Hmm, notational issues aside, $\mathbb{Z}/p$ in your example isn't $\textit{projective}$, so it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Victor, that reminds me. I've seen this ring turn up in another answer
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21765/projective-dimension/21766#21766
:-)

Comment: $K_0(R)=K^0(\textrm{Spec}R)$ so the variance make sense both ways.